# Openssl : What does RSA n e d p q parameters represent?

Tags: c, linux, openssl, rsa

What are the parameters `n, e, d, p, q` represent in below RSA structure for openssl ?

```
struct rsa_st
    {
    /* The first parameter is used to pickup errors where
     * this is passed instead of aEVP_PKEY, it is set to 0 */
    int pad;
    long version;
    const RSA_METHOD *meth;
    /* functional reference if 'meth' is ENGINE-provided */
    ENGINE *engine;
    BIGNUM *n;
    BIGNUM *e;
    BIGNUM *d;
    BIGNUM *p;
    BIGNUM *q;
    BIGNUM *dmp1;
    BIGNUM *dmq1;
    BIGNUM *iqmp;
    /* be careful using this if the RSA structure is shared */
    CRYPTO_EX_DATA ex_data;
    int references;
    int flags;

    /* Used to cache montgomery values */
    BN_MONT_CTX *_method_mod_n;
    BN_MONT_CTX *_method_mod_p;
    BN_MONT_CTX *_method_mod_q;

    /* all BIGNUM values are actually in the following data, if it is not
     * NULL */
    char *bignum_data;
    BN_BLINDING *blinding;
    BN_BLINDING *mt_blinding;
    };
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(algorithm)#Operation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as you can see from the openssl official page, their numbers with specific roles in calculating the ciphertext, [OpenSSL official documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/rsa.html)

I suggest you to take a gander at it, 
Bye!

EDIT 2018-07-27: update url
Linuxatico

Answer (score 7):

These are the parameters for the RSA algorithm:

p and q are two large prime numbers, and n is computed by p*q.
e is the public exponent, d is the multiplicative inverse of e mod (p-1)(q-1).

The private key is the pair (p, q). The public key is the pair (n, e)

You can learn more about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29).

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, `man 3 rsa` will give you a detailed explanation.